# Какие я могу тут вопросы задать?

Tags: поддержка

Какие я могу тут вопросы задать? Об всём или об технике?

Comment: а **[СПРАВКУ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)** почитать не?

Comment: В дополнение - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 5):

В первую очередь о программировании и администрировании.

В ограниченном количестве возможны вопросы на другие темы, но только если они очень хорошо сформулированы, чего, судя по этому вопросу, не заметно.

А вопросы, касающиеся тематики сайта, следует задавать на [мете](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/).